# Getting error when using Extension library and dojo in xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have installed domino designer 8.5.2,and Extension library 8.5.2,dojo 1.6.1.Then i have developed the Xpage using mobile apps controls.

When previewing the Xpage in the web,i am getting the error in console is given by

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)       /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js:14
failed loading /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/./parser.js with error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define        /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js:14
Error: Could not load 'dojo.parser'; last tried './parser.js'          /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js:14
failed loading /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/./hash.js with error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define         /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js:14
failed loading /xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/Mobile.js with error: Error: Could not load 'dojo.hash'; last tried './hash.js'        /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js:14
Error: Could not load 'extlib.dijit.Mobile'; last tried '/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/Mobile.js'             /domjs/dojo-release-1.6.1/ibm/domino/widget/layout/css/domino-default.cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Please could you help me what i need to do further....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domino 8.5.2 is shipped with Dojo 1.4.3 only.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Controls require Domino 8.5.3 because of the reliance on Dojo 1.6. See the post on OpenNTF http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8MHA78.

If you want to use mobile on 8.5.2, I think you will need to use the Mobile Controls project on OpenNTF which uses custom controls.

If possible, upgrade to 8.5.3. As well as performance benefits, it's easier to deploy the Extension Library and take advantage of the additional functionality that is only possible with the enhancements to the base code-set (such as RDBMS support, social etc.). Because 8.5.3 provides Dojo 1.6.1, this means your XPages will work on IE9 without forcing compatibility mode - outside of Compatibility Mode, IE9 does not support any version of Dojo earlier than 1.6.