# Could not load 'extlib.dijit.Mobile

Tags: xpages

I am getting the error Could not load 'extlib.dijit.Mobile in IE 8.   Using FF 17.0.7, I don't see such an error but the form does not display either.

I found this post
[Getting error when using Extension library and dojo in xpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579895/getting-error-when-using-extension-library-and-dojo-in-xpagesThat) says at least 8.5.3 is needed.   The server is running 8.5.3.

Edit: Opps wrong link corrected above

Any idea what is wrong?

I should be able to display a mobile app on my PC's browser correct?

Sorry but this is my first mobile app.

This is working locally on the browser but not on the server.  Are we missing something on the server that should have been installed?

Comment: Your code? You have declared that you use that dojo module in resources?

Comment: What do I need to add? I am following this tutorial http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Mobile_Controls_Tutorial_ and I do not see it mentioning a dojo resource.

Comment: In the page resources you can add a Dojo dependency: extlib.dijit.Mobile - It might be added in the Theme used in the tutorial. So best: download the extlib sample and look what they did. also consider the Teamstudio Mobile controls

Comment: I did download the sample.   Same thing.   As mentioned above it works local but not on the server.

Comment: Has Upgrade Pack 1 been installed on this server? While the mobile controls are native in 9, 8.5.3 requires either UP1 or the OpenNTF Extension Library in order for these components to be used.